Excel forecasting only allows for one business site to be selected at once?
I have a table similar to the below in Excel with the names of two business sites and their sales values for a number of months. Excel seems to have a good 'Forecast Sheet' function where I can select data and it creates a nice forecast output - however it only seems to allow me to select either Site A's data or Site B's, not produce an output with both summaries together? Is this accurate in terms of the limitation of the tool or if not can anyone advise what I am doing wrong please? Thank you.



Site
01/04/2023
01/05/2023




Site A
44
53


Site B
47
89




You could create the forecasts for the two sites separately so you end up with two tables and then update one of the charts to show info from both tables.  Or you could manually update the FORECAST.ETS manually.  I haven't used the Forecast Sheet functionality before but it seems to just add formula in a table and create a chart from it - something that could be done manually to suite your needs.
